# The deflator of reinsurance market is unique

Tags: finance-mathematics

How to prove that the deflator $\phi$ of the reinsurance market is unique when working in the equilibrium model?

That is, if we have a pricing function $\pi$, which satisfies:

$$\pi(Y)=E(\phi Y)$$

Then $\phi$ is unique. The pricing function is a function from random variables (claims amounts) to real numbers, and is linear.